# Velocity animations for leave callback of ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, velocity.js

I'm trying to get a leave animation working with velocity and angular so that when the table rows leave they move to the right.

In the example I use the leave callback to try an animate the leaving of ng-repeat but the callback runs however nothing happens!

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
    
    $scope.shiftItems = function() {
     var items = ['asdf', 'bill', 'bob', 'joe', 'items']
     
     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++)
       $scope.items.shift()
      
     for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
       $scope.items.push(items[i])
    }
  })

.animation('.velocity-tableSlideInOut', [function() {
    return {
      enter: function(element, done) {
         Velocity(element, 'transition.slideLeftIn', [0.36, 0.96, 0.6, 0.96])
       },

      leave: function(element) {
        Velocity(element, {opacity: 0}, [0.4, 0.04, 0.64, 0.04])
      }
    }
  }])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <ul ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <li class='velocity-tableSlideInOut' ng-repeat='item in items track by $index'>
      {{item}}
    </li>
    <li>
      <button ng-click='shiftItems()'>Reorder</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the expected behavior when using `track by $index`.

You start with 3 items and the indexes will be:

```
0 1 2
```

You remove those 3 items, add 6 new items and now have the indexes:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

No index has left, so no leave animation will be triggered. There are however 3 new indexes, so the enter animation will be triggered for the items with index 3, 4 and 5.

The solution is to either skip `track by` or to track by a property that is actually related to the object, for example an unique id. If your collection only contains strings and you need to support duplicates you will need to wrap them in objects, for example:

```
{ value: 'item1' }
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/tRZ7L0CAfFMKgSSyyYk5?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, it was actually to do with how i was manipulating the array simply reassigning it causes no animations!

Comment: Actually I noticed when changing the full list it doesn't animate out only in

Comment: Can you replicate the actual scenario in a plunker?